# Indentation for files that don't have a registered formatter

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

It seems that I am getting this problem since version 1.18, honestly I don't remember.
With VSCodeVim installed I used to press the `=` key to get my code (Elixir, embedded elixir, ...) indented properly.

Am I missing something, like a configuration, that would allow me to re-indent my files without having a nagging "Formatter for file x not installed".

This is honestly the only things that nags me with VSCode so far, love the speed, the capabilities and the UI...

Comment: Were you perhaps using the `reindent lines` command previously? This should work for many languages even if you don't have a formatting extension for that language installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just posting my comment as an answer*

Try using the `reindent lines` command. This command should work for many languages even if you don't have a formatting extension for that language installed

Answer (score -1):

Select the contents of file.Bottom right corner shows **spaces/tabs: 2/4**. You can click on that and indent the whole file.